# Error: Cannot find module 'togeojson'

Tags: node.js, npm

I am attempting to use this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/togeojson) in node.js and am running into an "Error: Cannot find module 'togeojson'" error when I attempt to use the documented example code:

```
// using togeojson in nodejs

var tj = require('togeojson'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    // node doesn't have xml parsing or a dom. use xmldom
    DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var kml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fs.readFileSync('foo.kml', 'utf8'));

var converted = tj.kml(kml);

var convertedWithStyles = tj.kml(kml, { styles: true });
```

I ran `npm init` in the same directory that my app.js file (where the above code resides) is stored and I used the `--save` flag when installing the @mapbox/togeojson package to my application.

I am running node version 8.11.2 and npm v 6.1.0.

How do I go about debugging an issue like this in node/npm?

Comment: Can you share your package-lock.json? How do you run this file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/p8VA0aMc is my package-lock.json file. I run my application as follows: `node app.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `@mapbox/togeojson` package, not `togeojson`, so it should be required like:

```
var tj = require('@mapbox/togeojson');
```